# Increase the font size of captions of sub-figures

Tags: graphics, captions

I have the following latex code to show two sub figures and their captions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\subfigure[Figure 1]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\label{figure:fig1}
}
\subfigure[Figure 2]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\label{figure:fig2}
}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

I want to increase the font size of the sub-captions and I have tried this:

```
\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\subfigure[\Large{Figure 1}]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\label{figure:fig1}
}
\subfigure[\Large{Figure 2}]{
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
\label{figure:fig2}
}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As shown in the above figure, this only makes the font of "Figure 1" part bigger, but not the "(a)" part of the caption of sub-figures.

How to increase the font size of sub-figures?

Comment: The package `subfigure` is completely outdated. Use `subfig` or `subcaption`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `subfigure` is obsolete and shouldn't be used any longer.

There are two alternatives: `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Use `\usepackage[font=Large]{subfig}` for larger caption labels, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=Large]{subfig}




\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\captionsetup[figure]{font=Large}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}

\centering
\subfloat[My first figure]{%
  \label{figure:fig1}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}
}

\subfloat[My second figure]{\label{figure:fig2}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{}}
\caption{My first figure}
\label{myfullfigure}

\end{figure}

In \subref{figure:fig1} we see this and in \ref{myfullfigure} we see all



\end{document}
```

[image]

The `subcaption` package provides `subfigure` etc. environments, which are easier to use, in my point of view

Comment: Thanks, that works. I have another issue, though. When I add more than 2 sub-figures, they do not appear one under the other. Any ideas?

Comment: @CoKoder - Have you tried inserting a blank line between the subfigures?

Comment: yes, I did. That did the trick, but subfigure package seems to do this automatically. Is there a better way than inserting a blank line?

Comment: @CoKoder: That's the way how `TeX` or `LaTeX` inserts a blank line: Leaving a blank line. Too easy? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you add an example using `subcaption`, since for many it's the preferred option?